# onlineUrs.map is not a function React Js Frontend

Tags: reactjs

I'm Trying to map api data in reactjs but when I trying to map the data it gives me error that map is not a function Please Help me I don't why it keeps
telling me that it's not a function,
please correct me I'm new to reactjs.

***TypeError: onlineUrs.map is not a function***

```
import React , { useEffect, useState }  from 'react'
import axios from "./axios.js"
import Header from "../dashbroad/Header.js";
import Sidebar from "../dashbroad/Sidebar.js";


function Online() {
  const [onlineUrs , setOnlineUrs] = useState([]);
  
  const config = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization : 'Bearer ' +  localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
};

useEffect(() =>{
  axios.get("http://localhost:8001/api/v1/active", config).then((response) => {
    setOnlineUrs(response.data);  

  });
});
 
console.log(onlineUrs)


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header/>
      <div className="app_body">

        <Sidebar />

        <div className="row_posters">
    {
      onlineUrs.map((item, index ) =>(
        <h1>{item.result}</h1>

      ))

    }
    
    </div>


</div>
  
</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Online
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map()` can be used only on arrays. In this situation it looks like onlineUrs is not an array or has not been set yet.

You could place something like this before invoking the map() function:

```js
onlineUrs && Array.isArray(onlineUrs) && onlineUrs.map((item, index) =>{
        <h1>{item.result}</h1>
      )}
```

If you api response is not an array, nothing will be rendered and won't break your code

Comment: Please accept the answer, upvote if you want and close the question :)